# Assign VLAN to multiple ports in SonicWALL TZ300

Tags: vlan, sonicwall, interface

I have a SonicWALL TZ300 with Cisco SG200-08 smart switches. My X1 interface is my WAN and my X0 interface is the default LAN.

My X2 interface is 192.168.1.1 and is in a custom public zone (LAN2). I have then created three VLANs within X2.

```
VLAN ID | Zone     | IP Address
--------|----------|-----------
2       | Business | 192.168.2.1
3       | Personal | 192.168.3.1
4       | WiFi     | 192.168.4.1
```

What I would like to do is have port 4 (X4 port) be part of the Business (2) VLAN without the need for another switch.

I tried adjusting some of the X4 interface settings, but can't seem to get it to be part of the Business (2) VLAN. Is this possible with the TZ300?

Answer (score 0):

Point to note:
SonicWall doesn't have the capability of operating on same vlan on two different interfaces.

Workaround:

1. Navigate to SonicWall Management UI > Network > Zones
2. Click configure button for LAN zone and enable interface trust
3. Click OK
4. Navigate to Firewall>Access Rules
5. Click Matrix
6. Select LAN > LAN
7. Add a rule with source:Any, Destination:Any and Service: Any
8. Click OK

Try testing with this setup.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to configure this on Sonicwall.

**Workaround for Layer3 and upwards:**

If there's no need for layer2 communication between two business networks, go with an additional interface that is assigned to the same ("Business") zone and enable [interface trust](https://support.software.dell.com/kb/sw3769).

But be aware: You'll have to different subnets afterwards for the "Business" zone. Things like providing an DHCP server on port 1 and accessing it from port 4 will not be possible without additional configuration.

---

You'll propably have to bite the bullet, get an additional switch (if you're existing switches are completely occupied) and setup the distribution of the VLANs there (which in general is a much better solution than doing this on the firewall)

Answer (score 0):

This is possible on the SonicWAll UTM appliances and has been for several years you just need to think outside the box :), all you need to is put X4 in the WLAN Zone (select no sonicpoints) and L2 bridge to the Sub interface VLAN 2, you will need to also edit the WLAN zone in the Zone settings and turn off the option in the Wireless tab to only allow access from a SonicPoint, the rules should auto create but if you have issues auto detecting printers etc enable Interface trust on the WLAN Zone

or another way you could do this with the latest firmware is to use the Native Bridge feature and bridge X4 to the VLAN 2